# How to prevent quoting of column name in SQL in Yii2

Tags: php, sql, yii2

I want to write SQL like this with Yii 2:

```
select id, 1 as type from user;
```

This is my code:

```
$query = User::find()->select(['id', '1 as type'])->all();
```

`1` is a constant, not user's field

I want to add field `type = 1` to the query result.

Answer (score 11):

To disable quoting and escaping in certain part of the query, wrap it in [yii\db\Expression](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-expression.html):

```
use yii\db\Expression;

...

$query = User::find()->select(['id', new Expresssion('1 as type')])->all();
```

Comment: really awesome when you work with unions and you want to return the tablename

Comment: Is using yii\db\Expression safe for sql injection attacks? How would you do complex queries where you may need to use Expression() but also make sure it's safe?